# Import obj ad texture and export aws obj,

Tags: uv, export

I am totally new to blender! I have a program the produces an obj and mtl file, when viewed however all the texture info is gone they are plain objects. 
**My question is how to add a texture to these OBJ files and export the obj with textures intact.**

I can save the texture files manually(in aforementioned program) and add them in latter after import to blender. Would one delete the mtl file prior to import so that its correctly added on export?!

I have watch a few youtube vids and looked at some of the answers on here but none seem to fit. One said to switch from object mode to edit mode, but the bottom panel has no option to enter 'edit mode'  only 'object mode'.

Can any one help?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/

Answer (score -1):

you can't export Obj file included texture in it. if you want to transfer your Obj you should transfer your texture too; then attach texture to Obj from new directory.

for using edit mode in blender 2.79 you can use "tab" Button. in blender 2.8 press "tab" then select edit mode.

Comment: When I click or rather use the tab key it appears to do nothing I'm really in need of an answer to the in **bold question.** Thanks for your import to the discussion.